# Why Acr.UserDialogs doesn't show the loading?

Tags: c#, xamarin

I'm trying to show loading using Acr.UserDialogs on Xamarin. I want to show the loading while I will getting some informations on WebService but it does not works, the loading just not showing.

How could I fix this ?

**Trying**

```
private async void OnClickAcessar(object sender, EventArgs args){
            var _loading = UserDialogs.Instance.Loading("Wait...", null, null, true, MaskType.Clear);

            try {                         

                //user object
                Usuario usuario = new Usuario();
                usuario.email = Email.Text;
                usuario.senha = Senha.Text;

                //webservice                
                Usuario u = UsuarioService.Login(usuario);  

                //alert                
                if (u != null && u.status == 1){                  
                    App.Current.MainPage = new MainView();
                }else{
                    await DisplayAlert("Error", "User or Password error", "OK");
                    Email.Focus();
                }

            }catch(Exception e){
                Debug.WriteLine("Erro: " + GetType().Name + " ->" + e.Message);
                await DisplayAlert("Erro", e.Message, "OK");
            }
            finally{                
                _loading.Hide();
            }    

        }
```

Comment: I just test and your code works well on my side. You can try to run dialog on main thread. If you can provide us a Minimal, Reproducible Example, I will check it for you:).

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.device.begininvokeonmainthread?view=xamarin-forms) to run dialog on main thread, however it's working for me without this method. Or you can use:

```
UserDialogs.Instance.ShowLoading("Wait...");
UserDialogs.Instance.HideLoading();
```